# What is the practical difference between spring rate and damper bump in Dirt Rally?

Tags: dirt-rally

I've read that springs store energy, while dampers control the rate at which the energy is stored or released. What's the practical difference between these two settings? What's the result of a soft spring rate with a stiff bump setting, or vice versa, compared to setting both to soft or both to firm?